# Developer options don't save changes

Tags: android, user-interface

I configure "Developer options" hidden menu on Android app (I need to enable USB debugging).
But this (and other) changes in this menu do no apply.
When i try to use features or go to "Developer options" again, my changes are discarded.

I use Huawei P40 lite, Android 10, EMUI 10.0.1

How to apply my changes?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem when I attached computer via USB and enabled all debug-related toggle buttons.